# How to add custom font as Magento base font

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, javascript, css, html

i am new in magento and i want to change my magento base font.

i found this code:

```
@font-face {   font-family: 'MyWebFont';   src: url('BYekan.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */   src: url('BYekan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('BYekan.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('BYekan.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('BYekan.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */ }
```

and i have this font files:

```
BYekan.woff
BYekan.eot
BYekan.ttf
```

where should i copy that code? and where should i upload font files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found answer here:
Custom typography in Magento – @font-face

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-typography-in-magento-font-face/

Answer (score 0):

I found the absolute easiest way is to go to ***System->Configuration***

There from the General group go to Design and on the HTML Head section use the Misc Scripts to paste something like this:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style> body {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !Important;}</style>
```

Where the link is for the desired google font (why would you need any other?)

Cheers.